# Derive parameters from Access Query using C#

Tags: ms-access

I have a query in microsoft Access that accepts few parameters. I'm looking for an example in C# that will let me be able to "Derive" parameters from the query first before populating them with values.

Can this be done? Please tell me how asap.

There are many questions like this in in other sites in the web but with no answer.

Comment: Please post the sql of the query.

Comment: my query is an insert query:
INSERT INTO STUDENTS(studentName, age) VALUES ([_studentName], [_age]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can see of doing this is with DAO, but there may be others.

```
DBEngine dbEng = new DBEngine();
Workspace Ws = dbEng.CreateWorkspace("", "admin", "", WorkspaceTypeEnum.dbUseJet);
Database Db = Ws.OpenDatabase(@"Z:\Docs\Test.accdb", false, false, "");

QueryDef qry = Db.QueryDefs["MyStoredQuery"];
foreach (Parameter prm in qry.Parameters)
{
    Console.WriteLine(prm.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(prm.Type);
}
```

The only way you will get an accurate type is if you include a Parameter statement :

```
PARAMETERS param1 Text ( 255 ), param2 Integer;
```

Comment: This was helpful, but this DAO is pretty old, right? Can this be done using any of the new db access such as OleDB or Jet?

Comment: DAO is not old it is regularly updated, that was done using the latest DAO library from Access 2010, `Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library`. Jet is old, the latest Access database engine is ACE. For the most part, you are better using DAO with Access. I am not saying OleDB is impossible, but I do not know how to get parameters for Access with it, and it *is* old, and soon to be discontinued support in favour of ODBC in SQL Server, for one.